# chart.js not working in browser with django. no error for template and static folder setting

Tags: javascript, django, chart.js

I have created view to render simple HTML page which uses bootstrap and chart.js

bootstrap working properly but chart is not getting displayed.

there is not error in code. no error regarding Staticfile and Directory setup.

However, Chart is not displaying in page.

is there any prerequisite for chart.js or it does not work with Django.

Comment: show your code what you have done.Your view,html and model

Comment: you can check this blog charts.js with django :https://godjango.com/blog/using-chartjs-with-django/

Comment: chart.js is only on the frontend. Therefore it also works with Django. Try including the standard snippet from http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/ and see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Django-ChartJS is what you want to use to intgrate into Django and it has an excellent sample.
https://pypi.org/project/django-chartjs/#description

NOTE; You still need to need to download chartjs and put it in your static files.

Comment: Thank you Patrick. I will try this link. In the mean time I used Highchart.js which I found easy to use.